# Verification of using Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I am asked to find what is $5^{102}$ in $Z_{11}$:

The answer I have is as follows:

$5^{10}=1$ by Fermat's Little Theorem 
So $(5^{10})^{10}$=$5^{100}=1$
So $5^{102}$=$5^2$=4 in $Z_{11}$

Is this right?  Where did the $4$ come from?  I thought 25 in $Z_{11}$ was $3$?  or did my instructor make a typo here?

Answer (score 5):

You wrote $5^2 = 4 $ mod $11$.

But $25$ $ mod $ $11 = 3.$

And thus not $4$.

So the correct answer is $3$.

Your reasoning was correct.